# Box2d - Motionless body velocity bounces around before 0

Tags: box2d, velocity, truncate

I was testing the linear velocity of a body.

I move the body around using applyforce coordinated with the w-a-s-d keys.

I noticed that, even when the body is visually stationary, when the simulation begins, the velocity bounces around at various positive and negative values.

Eventually, the velocity goes to zero, and then seems to be accurate during the movement while I'll move the body around.

However, once I stop the movement, for several seconds, the velocity bounces around in very large positive/negative values before settling on zero and remaining there until it is moved again.

What I think is happening is the motion is somehow 'overshooting' the position it is trying to reach, and the distance between the body and the position gradually shrinks until it presumably truncates and hits zero.

The 'motionless' values are often as large as the moving values, and this will surely create corner-case bugs if I can't fix it.

Is there a way to make the velocity quickly hit zero (and stay there) when there isn't any visually significant movement?

Comment: Depending on the language your using box2d in you can add linearDamping which adds a constant resistance to the linear velocity. https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef.html#linearDamping

Comment: @dfour Sounds like it's probably the solution.

Comment: Looks like your doing this in c++ from a previous question so you should check out iforce2d.net which is the goto wiki for c++ box2d http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/

Comment: Where is the body in question when the simulation begins? Is it on a static body acting as a ground? What's the gravity set to?

Comment: @dfour I cranked the linear dampening and this sadly had no effect.

Comment: @LouisLangholtz It's a top down simulation, so no ground. Though adding one is maybe the fix?\

Comment: What sort of values are you using for size as box2d doesn't work well when the sizes are too big or too small. I tend to keep things between 0.1 and 20.

Comment: The body belongs to a structure made up of about 5 other bodies that are welded together.

Comment: Sizes are between 0.1 and 1. Density is at 0.1 for all structures.

Comment: Gravity is at 0,0

Comment: Okay, the answers were actually just really, really small and Java println was giving scientific notation which made me think they were huge. D'oh moment.